# How to fix "apt-get install -f apt-transport-https" error: 404 Not Found?

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, deb

We have a pair of load balanced managed VMs which install apt-transport-https as part of a startup script.

However recently the servers went into an error state because on startup they could no longer download the version of the package required (1.0.9.8.3) because it is no longer present on the mirror: http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt

```
root@validator-dev-group-c2v4:/etc# apt-get install -f apt-transport-https
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-transport-https
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
Need to get 138 kB of archives.
After this operation, 195 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main apt-transport-https amd64 1.0.9.8.3
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/apt-transport-https_1.0.9.8.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Trying the suggestion of `--fix-missing` does not help.

```
root@validator-dev-group-c2v4:/etc# apt-get install --fix-missing apt-transport-https
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  apt-transport-https
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 27 not upgraded.
Need to get 138 kB of archives.
After this operation, 195 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Err http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie/main apt-transport-https amd64 1.0.9.8.3
  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/apt-transport-https_1.0.9.8.3_amd64.deb  404  Not Found
E: Internal Error, ordering was unable to handle the media swap
```

Next I manually downloaded the higher version of apt-transport-https (1.0.9.8.4) bug I was unable to install it directly because of a dependency on libapt-pkg4.12.

```
root@validator-dev-group-c2v4:/home/<user># sudo dpkg -i ./apt-transport-https_1.0.9.8.4_amd64.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package apt-transport-https.
(Reading database ... 26719 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apt-transport-https_1.0.9.8.4_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking apt-transport-https (1.0.9.8.4) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of apt-transport-https:
 apt-transport-https depends on libapt-pkg4.12 (>= 1.0.9.8.4); however:
  Version of libapt-pkg4.12:amd64 on system is 1.0.9.8.3.
```

Can anyone help me resolve this problem? Is it as simple as upgrading libapt-pkg4.12? If so, how do I go about that?

**EDIT**: Also I am unable to run `apt-get update` ... because I haven't got `apt-transport-https` installed. Which I think they call Catch-22!

```
root@validator-dev-group-c2v4:/home/<user># apt-get update
E: The method driver /usr/lib/apt/methods/https could not be found.
N: Is the package apt-transport-https installed?
```

This is what my `/etc/apt/sources.list` looks like:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you run `apt-get update` recently?  You should have an updated list of what's available from the repositories, before you try to install any given package.  404 is likely happening because you're trying to install a version of the package that is no longer on the repository servers.

Comment: Good question. I forgot to mention this, so I'll edit the question. I can't run `apt-get update` because I haven't got apt-transport-https installed!!! A nice Catch-22

Comment: Better to have your own repo, so you don't depend on an external one.

Comment: Do you have anything in files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`?

Comment: Only lines already present in `sources.list`:
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main
None of the entries in either location contain 'https://' URLs though?

Comment: Indeed, perhaps the redirector is sending you to an HTTPS mirror...

Comment: Renaming the **http** to **https** in **/usr/lib/apt/methods/** solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you @Bethwel Too, this has solved an issue on the now defunct C.H.I.P.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I appear to have fixed the issue by symlinking the `https` dir in `/usr/lib/apt/methods` to the `http` dir.

```
root@validator-dev-group-c2v4:~# cd /usr/lib/apt/methods
root@validator-dev-group-c2v4:/usr/lib/apt/methods# ln -s http https
```

Since I don't actually have any `https://` sources configured it seems harmless and then when `apt-get install apt-transport-https` runs it actually overwrites the symlink with the correct files.

Comment: This is actually a good idea. Thank you for posting your solution.

Comment: Awesome trick, worked like a charm!

Comment: use `$ sudo ln -s http https`, if the currently logged in user is not root.

Answer (score 7):

The general solution is to update `apt`'s indexes so it knows which versions are available:

```
apt-get update
```

Then installing `apt-transport-https` will find the appropriate versions on the repositories.

You should do this every time you want to install a new package, unless you've done it recently (within the last day typically).

If you can't run `apt-get update` because it needs `apt-transport-https`, you can fix things by (temporarily) switching your `https://` URLs to `http://` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` (and perhaps files in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`). Using HTTP to download packages doesn't reduce your security, it only reduces your confidentiality (systems between your computer and the repositories can see what packages you're retrieving).

If *that* doesn't work, you can try picking a specific mirror, which should avoid any redirections to HTTPS URLs; look at the [list](https://www.debian.org/mirror/list), pick a mirror close to you and use that instead of `httpredir.debian.org` in your sources.

In your specific case it may well be simpler to manually download the required packages (and ship them alongside your setup scripts so that they continue working): `apt-transport-https`, `libapt-pkg4.12` and whatever else is necessary. (You may end up needing to upgrade `apt` at the same time.)

Comment: I can't run `apt-get update` because I haven't got `apt-transport-https` installed!

Comment: Ah yes, see my update.

Comment: None of the URLs in either `sources.list` or `sources.list.d` are HTTPS.

Comment: OK, you could try another mirror, or just manually download everything.

Answer (score 3):

There are a bunch of text files containing the URL for downloading apt packages within the folder `/etc/apt/`

Example name for those text files can be:  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list` if you try to install packages from a Microsoft server.

And the content of `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list` could be :

`deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/8/prod jessie main`

Sometimes the content from `*.list` files is downloaded via HTTPS instead of HTTP but if you have not installed the package `apt-transport-https`, you wouldn't be able to update your apt-get package manager. It will keep warning you about not being able to use the HTTPS sources.

What you can do then is to locate the offending `*.list` file(s) with HTTPS links and rename it: 

`sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list1
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install -y apt-transport-https 
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list1 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list
sudo apt-get update`

Then you should be able to proceed with whatever apt-get operations you wish to perform.

Reference for coming up with this answer
https://community.c9.io/t/installing-apt-transport-https-issue/10994/10

Comment: This is what allowed me to unbreak our entire companies build process when a docker image pointing to an old mono repo stopped working.  
`RUN find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -exec bash -c 'mv $1 ${1}.bak' -- {} \; && \
 apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https && \
 find /etc/apt/sources.list.d -type f -exec bash -c 'mv $1 ${1//.bak}' -- {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

In my case (Ubuntu 20.04 LTS) the problem seemed to have to do with package `python3-aiozmq` depending to `python-3.5` or not working:

```
The following packages will be upgraded:
  apt-transport-https
1 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 39 not to upgrade.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 4.680 B of archives.
After this operation, 1.024 B of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ftp.belnet.be/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 apt-transport-https all 2.0.6 [4.680 B]
Fetched 4.680 B in 0s (24,3 kB/s)               
(Reading database ... 600039 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../apt-transport-https_2.0.6_all.deb ...
Unpacking apt-transport-https (2.0.6) over (2.0.5) ...
Setting up python3-aiozmq (0.7.1-2) ...
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/aiozmq/rpc/base.py", line 251
    fut = asyncio.async(coro, loop=self.loop)
                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

dpkg: error processing package python3-aiozmq (--configure):
 installed python3-aiozmq package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Setting up apt-transport-https (2.0.6) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python3-aiozmq
```

It seems the problem has been fixed in the next version ('[0.9](https://packages.debian.org/sid/python3-aiozmq)'), but the new version is not there yet (so `apt-get update` won't fix the problem for now). The way I solved this was to manually download it:

```
wget http://ftp.it.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/aiozmq/python3-aiozmq_0.9.0-1_all.deb
```

And then manually remove the problematic package and install it:

```
sudo apt remove python3-aiozmq
sudo dpkg -i python3-aiozmq_0.9.0-1_all.deb
```

After that, `sudo apt install apt-transport-https` just worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

You can execute following command:

```
apt-get update && apt-get -y install apt-transport-https curl
```

Answer (score -2):

you have to add your proxy settings in case absence of their settings are causing issues to get the package.
you can set http_proxy, https_proxy, no_proxy in your system/shell settings.
I myself was facing similar issue in installing apache superset.

Comment: Your last sentence seems to have been cut off. Also, the OP made no mention of a proxy...?